# Is manipulating a global function definition inside another function bad practice?

Tags: python, function, global

I have a function called `set_func` that is 25 lines long. Inside it calls `update`.

```py
def set_func(table: str, identifier=None, **kwargs) -> None:
    ... # does stuff with arguments
    query = update(table, kwargs, identifier)
    ...
    execute(query)
```

I want to declare a function called `delete_func` that does the exact same thing, but instead of calling `update` it would call `delete`.

My code:

```py
def delete_func(table: str, identifier=None) -> None:
    global update
    backup_update = deepcopy(update)
    assert backup_update is not update

    update = delete
    try:
        return set_func(table, identifier)
    finally:
        update = backup_update
```

This works, buy it seems bad practice. Is there another way to do this without changing `set_func`? Is it bad code?

Comment: You can make a function that takes in the operation ('set' or 'delete') and call different functions based on that.

Comment: Write a function that accepts either `update` or `delete` as an argument, then call whatever function is passed. No global variables are needed.

Comment: Why not change `set_func`? Is it third-party code?

Comment: At the very least, you don't need to *copy* the function. `backup_update = update; update = delete; ...; update = backup_update` will suffice. The assignments don't affect the old value of the name.

Comment: For a general answer: [Why are global variables evil?](/q/19158339/4518341)

Comment: I'll could do some type of "function inheritance" like Fractalism and chepner proposed. Buy I asked if my code has a bad smell. It looks this way simpler I believe.

Comment: @LucasNapon It definitely does not look good. And it does not really seem simpler.

Comment: you might alter `set_func()` to accept a work function then pass either `update()` or `delete()` to it.

Comment: Functions are first-class values; passing a function as an argument is no more like inheritance than passing an `int` value. Even `update` and `delete` are just variable with values of type `function`, not the functions themselves. (The only difference is that the names were assigned the values by a `def` statement, rather than an assignment statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since functions are first class, I would probably pass whatever work was to be done into your method as a parameter. Alternatively, you could pass in a flag and internally determine how to process the work. I would definitely NOT change the implementation as you have done here even if it technically worked.

I might do something like this:

```py
def fn_update(table: str, identifier, **kwargs) -> None:
    # do whatever you do to just update
    return "query"

def fn_delete(table: str, identifier, **kwargs) -> None:
    # do whatever you do to just delete
    return "query"

def set_func(fn_work, table: str, identifier=None, **kwargs) -> None:
    ... # does stuff with arguments
    query = fn_work(table, identifier, kwargs)
    ...
    execute(query)
```